# Is the minimal distance from a point inside a paralellopiped to its 8 vertices always less than the maximal length of all edges?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is the minimal distance from a point inside a paralellopiped to its 8 vertices is always less than the maximal length of all edges?

Note that for an extreme case, the center of a unit cube has distance $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}<1$ to its vertices.

I can prove that if a point $X$ from the interior of a paralellopiped  lies in a "corner" tetrahedron say, in the following picture, $ABCF$, then
$BX$ is less than $\max(BA,BC,BF)$, which is the same as the maximum of lengths all edges. But not every point lies in one of these eight "corner" tetrahedra, for example the center.

[image]

Comment: Can you prove it for a parallelogram ( a very flat parallelepiped)?

Comment: @orangeskid : A very flat case is helpful when we prove the general case ?

Comment: You can look at $\min \{ XA, XB, \ldots \}$ as a function of $X$. Probably (possibly) its maximum is achieved at the center.

Comment: Could you write an elaborated answer ? Why does the function you made achieve maximum at center ?

Comment: We can guess just that the problem that the function you made achieves maximum at center could be the another form of the original problem.

Comment: @orangeskid I can prove it but it is not helpful for the dimension three case. Here is a sketch: split the parallelogram into two triangles and any point will fall into one of them. By joining the vertex to that point it is not hard to see the length is less than the max of edges. In dimension three you can only prove it for those eight "corner" tetrahedra

Comment: @orangeskid I have thought about doing that optimization thing. But that is doable for me only in the case of cuboid not paralellopiped

Comment: If you look at the Voronyj  cells for a parallelogram you notice that there are two points of maximum for the min function, the centers of the inscribed circles of the acute triangles. It is interesting. Maybe it works similarly in 3 d.

Comment: @HK Lee: I was mistaken, the function achieves the minimum at some other points in general. We can see that in the 2 d case.

Comment: Minimum distance for any point is not greater than for center. Let edges are $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, $\vec{c}$ and $a$ is maximal edge length. Distance $d$ from center to any vertex is half of length of some vector $\pm\vec{a}\pm\vec{b}\pm\vec{c}$. $4d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2\pm2 \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\pm2\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}\pm2\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}$. Varying signs we can always get $\pm2 \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\pm2\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}\pm2\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}\leq 0$, then $4d^2_{min}\leq a^2+b^2+c^2 \leq 3a^2$, $d_{min}\leq a\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: @Ivan Kaznacheyeu : You have just tried to prove that minimum distance of center is not greater than maximum length of edges. And further, Could you clarify $\pm a\cdot b \pm b\cdot c \pm c\cdot a\leq o$ ?

Comment: minimum distance of center is greater than minimum distance of general point ? Could you prove this ?

Comment: I didn't try to prove first fact. I've taken it as intuitive. Unfortunately it is wrong. I've just proven that for center minimum distance is not greater than $a\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. This does not solve the problem, but I believe the same method can be used to solve original problem.

Comment: We can take any signs in sum $\pm\vec{a}\pm\vec{b}\pm\vec{c}$ independently. We can first fix sign of $\vec{a}$, then we can select sign of $\vec{b}$ in order to make $\pm\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\leq 0$, then we can select sign of $\vec{c}$ in order to make $\pm\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}\pm\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c} \leq 0$.

Comment: The fact about center can be wrong for 2D, therefore it can be wrong for 3D. Let take such parallelogram that center is not point of maximum $d_{min}$. Let set points E,D,C,F (see picture in question) in vertices of this parallelogram. Now let set point A far from plane EDCF. Then construct parallelepiped AEHDBFGC. Then take point of maximum $d_{min}$ for 2D case inside parallelogram EDCF. This point will have greater $d_{min}$ for 3D case than center.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt:

Here is the 2d case of a parallelogram. We draw the [Voronyi cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) for the set of vertices $V$. The magenta points are the the points inside the parallelogram where the function
$$X \mapsto d(X, V)$$
achieves its maximum. They are the centers of the circumscribed circles for the the two acute triangles. This maximum value is $R$, the radius of the circles. It is easy to see that $2 R < l + l'$, the sum of two sides.

[image]

In the 3d case, we could imagine that the points of maximum are again the centers of the acute tetrahedrons, two of them.

$\bf{Added:}$ In 3d looking at the Voronyi cells could be difficult. However, there is another method that would work say for (semi-)regular polytopes. Use the fact that

$$\sum XA_i^2 - n X C^2$$
is constant, where $C$ is the center of mass of the set of points $X_i$. This allows us to show  that the center of the regular polytope is where the function $d$ achieves its maximum ( intuitive).

$\bf{Added:}$ Consider a finite set of points $V$ in space, and $D$ a closed bounded domain.  The function

$$X\mapsto d(X,V)$$
achieves it maximum on $D$. Let's show that if $X_0$ is a point of maximum inside $D$, then the distance $d(X_0, V)$ is achieved for at least $4$ points in $V$. Indeed, otherwise write the distances from $X_0$ to points in $V$ in increasing order

$$d_1 = d_2 = d_3 < d_4 \cdots$$

Now, we can move $X_0$ ever so slightly (along an axis) to $X_0'$ so that the distances become

$$d_1' = d_2' = d_3'< d_4'\cdots$$

and $d_1' > d_1$, contradiction with maximality.

Conclusion: $X_0$ is either on the boundary of $D$, or is inside $D$, and is the center of a circumscribed sphere of $4$ points in $V$.

Comment: It it possible that also the magenta points are outside the parallelogram.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** Assume that $X$ is an interior point in
the parallelepiped $P=A_1A_2A_3A_4$-$A_5A_6A_7A_8 $ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Prove that the minimum distance from $X$ to vertices is strictly smaller
than maximum length of edges in $P$.

**Proof : (a)** Consider a triangle $\Delta XAB, \ A=A_1,\
B=A_2$ with side lengths $$x=|XA|,\ y=|XB|,\ z=|AB|$$ and $\theta =
\angle \ AXB$. Assume that
$$ x \geq y \geq z
$$

Then prove that $$ \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$$

**Proof :** By **2nd Cosine Law**, we have $$
x^2+y^2-2xy\cos\ \theta = z^2 $$

If $\theta > \frac{\pi}{3}$, then $\cos\ \theta <\frac{1}{2}$ so
that $$\frac{ x^2+y^2-z^2}{2xy} =\cos\ \theta < \frac{1}{2} $$

which is a contradiction.

**(b)** If there is $\theta$ with $\theta >
\frac{\pi}{3}$, then $z>y$. Hence we complete the proof.

We will assume that $$ \angle A_iXA_j \leq
 \frac{\pi}{3}$$ for all edges $[A_iA_j]$ in $P$.

We define $$ a_i = \frac{A_i-X}{|A_i-X|} \in \mathbb{S}^2$$

Hence if $|\ast - \ast |$ is a distance function on
$\mathbb{S}^2$, then $|a_i-a_j| \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$ where $[A_iA_j]$
is an edge.

If $A_1,\ A_7$ are in diagonal position, then $$|a_1-a_7| \leq
|a_1-a_2| + |a_2-a_6|+|a_6-a_7| \leq \pi $$

If $M$ is a mid point between $a_1$ and $a_7$ (We have at least one
$M$), then we consider an open hemisphere $H$ s.t. $\partial H$ is a
great circle $M^\perp$
and $H$ contains $a_1,\ a_7$.

In $\mathbb{S}^2$, we consider a broken geodesic for example $\alpha
= [a_1a_4]\cup [a_4a_8] \cup [a_8a_7]$ whose length is $\leq \pi$.
If $\alpha'$ is $\pi$-**rotation-image** of $\alpha$ wrt $M$, then
$\alpha\cup\alpha'$ is a loop of length $\leq 2\pi$.

If this loop
escapes the closed hemisphere $\overline{H}$, then *it intersects
$\partial H$ at some point $h$*. Clearly, if $h'$ is
$\pi$-rotation-image of $h$ wrt $M$, then the loop contains both
points $h,\ h'$, which implies that this loop is in the great arc
between $h,\ h'$.

Hence points $a_4,\ a_8$ are also in the
hemisphere $\overline{H}$. In the long run all points $a_i$ are in
the hemisphere $\overline{H}$. Note that *this is possible only when
$X$ is not an interior point*. Hence we complete the proof.